# AND, OR use In Join query in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, join

How to use Below query in Codeigniter

SELECT * FROM (`post`) JOIN `user` ON `user`.`user_id`=`post`.`user_id` JOIN `friend` ON (`friend`.`user_id`=`post`.`user_id` AND friend.friendship_id=1) OR (friend.user_id=1 ANDfriend.friendship_id=post.user_id) WHERE `post`.`type` = 'friend' ORDER BY `postid` desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this.

```
$this->db->query(your query);
```

like this code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = 1";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks It Working

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('post')
    ->join('user', 'user.user_id = post.user_id')
    ->join('friend', 'friend.user_id = (post.user_id AND friend.friendship_id=1) OR (friend.user_id = 1 AND friend.friendship_id = post.user_id)')
    ->where('post.type', 'friend')
    ->order_by('postid','DESC')
    ->get();

$arrResult = $query->result();
```